# VUE.js & v-mask - mask not applied after a fetch

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm learning VUE.js and faced a newbie problem.

When i fetch some json data in a rest service and fill v-model with returned data, the mask wasn't applied.

When I fill the input manually, the mask works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
<v-text-field label="Phone" placeholder="(XX) XXXX-XXXXX" outlined v-mask="'(##) ####-#####'" v-model="data.phone"></v-text-field>

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      data: { 
        phone: ''
      }
    },
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    mounted() {
          // Simple GET request using fetch
          fetch("test.json")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => (this.data = data.data));
    }
    
});

my json
{
    "data": {
          "name": "525235235",
          "phone": "1234",
          "mobile": "5678"
    }
}
```

if I change to:

```
    created() {
          // Simple GET request using fetch
            this.data.phone = '124456'; 
           
    }
```

everything works fine.

If I use simple input, everything works fine too.

```
<input type="text" v-model="data.phone" v-mask="'(##) ####-#####'"></input>

´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your returned json is not ok?

```
this.data = data.data.phone
```

or

```
this.data.phone = data.data
```

or

```
this.data = data.phone
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think my json is ok. Fields were filled ok, with json values, but not masked. this.data = data.data fills all fields in form (incluinding phone field).

Answer (score 0):

Add `return-masked-value` to fix this issue.

```
<v-text-field label="Phone" placeholder="(XX) XXXX-XXXXX" outlined v-mask="'(##) ####-#####'" v-model="data.phone" return-masked-value></v-text-field>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it not worked. Looking in another questions i think return-masked-value works for vue native mask (removed in newer versions), not v-mask. Can I try something else?

Comment: Use a package for masking.

Comment: There are two packages that you can use.

Comment: 1) vue-the-mask.       2) v-mask.

Comment: shahidiqbal, this example is using v-mask. Did you use v-mask anytime? If you have to fetch some data (like an edit form), the masks show up ok?

Comment: I've used vue-the-mask . You''re using vuetify right?

Comment: shahidiqbal, Yes, I'm using vuetify. I changed to primevue and its bundled  inputmask works perfect. I don't know what happen with vuetify + third party library, like v-mask. With normal input (vue input maybe?) everything works fine too. Well, i'm still testing another libraries to learn more about Vue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should assign value in created() not in mounted()